# A problem related to remainder.

Tags: real-analysis

Find remainder when $2^{40}$ is divided by 34.
Please help me in solving the question. I tried it by using binomial theorem but as binomial theorem needs two terms it was unsuccessful. I think answer is 8 or 16. But I am not sure

Comment: It's $18$, I'd say.

Comment: Can you post the method please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An very easy method using binomial theorem . 
$2^{40}$ = ($2^{5})^{8}$ = $32^{8}$ =$(34-2)^{8}$.
Now  by  using binomial theorem last term will leave remainder when divided by 34.
Now , $^8C_8$ $2^{8}$ = $2^{8}$ = 256.
Now remainder is 256/34 =18

Answer (score 0):

$2^4=-1\pmod{17}$, so $2^{40}=(2^4)^{10}=1\pmod{17}$. That means $2^{40}=17n+1$, and since a power of $2$ is even, n must be odd, i.e. $2^{40}=17(2m+1)+1=34m+18$.
EDIT: If you don't know and don't want to learn modular arithmetic, you can do it simply by hand: $2^{40}=(2^{10})^4=1048576^2=1099511627776$, dividing it by $34$ isn't difficult even by hand, with a calculator, you get $1099511627776/34=32338577287.529411764705882352941$ and $1099511627776-34\cdot32338577287=18$.

Comment: Actually I don't know what is mod is there any other method

Comment: @AtharvaShetty: $a\equiv b \pmod c$ just means that $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$2^5\equiv 32 \mod 34$$ and by squaring $$2^{10}\equiv 4 \mod 34$$ and $$2^{20}\equiv 16 \mod 34$$ and finally $$2^{40}\equiv 16^2\equiv 18\mod 34$$

Comment: The OP doesn't know modular arithmetics, as we know now, moreover, there is a typo in the last line.